# "DiscordApi cannot be resolved to a type" Discord Java Eclipse Bot

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, discord

```
package Bots;
public class FirstBot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Insert your bot's token here
        String token = "TheToken";

        DiscordApi api = new DiscordApiBuilder().setToken(token).login().join();
        String prefix = "!";
        // Add a listener which answers with "Pong!" if someone writes "!ping"
        api.addMessageCreateListener(event -> {
            if (event.getMessageContent().equalsIgnoreCase(""+prefix+"ping")) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("Pong!");
            }
        });

        // Print the invite url of your bot
        System.out.println("You can invite the bot by using the following url: " + api.createBotInvite());
    }
}
```

I am new to creating Discord bots in Java. I am using Eclipse and i used this starter code ^
It is giving me an error that **DiscordApi cannot be resolved to a type** and **DiscordApiBuilder cannot be resolved to a type**

Comment: Are you importing the classes?

Comment: I don't think so. I probably not importing any classes. I think I have to download some Maven thing. Not very sure. I also don't know which ones I have to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is make sure that you have the JavaCord Maven dependency set up correctly.

Add this inside the `<dependencies>` field of your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javacord</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacord</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

The next step is to shade the JavaCord package into your final jar, so that you can run it directly. Add this to your pom.xml:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.javacord</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>your.package.name.here.dependencies.javacord</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If you already have a `<build>` or `<plugins>` field, put it within that.

The final step is to import the relevant JavaCord classes into your main class. If you try to type out the class names again, Eclipse should offer the option to import them.